# What is geometrical interptetation of a set being measurable.

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, intuition, geometric-interpretation

What is geometrical interptetation of a set being measurable. I mean what does it mean geometrically by a set is measurable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $\mathbb{R}^n$ with Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, non-measurable sets are pretty pathological, and their constructions depend on the Axiom of Choice, the axiom that allows you to [split a ball into two identical ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox).

Measurable sets are where $\lambda$ can act "properly". That is, any union of disjoint measurable sets has measure equal to the sum of individual measures.

The geometrical interpretation of a Lebesgue non-measurable set would be an object **without** a volume.

Comment: Sir can you give an example of non measurable set and apply your interpretation.

Comment: @Rayees while it is not too hard to show that nonmeasurable sets exist, the proof is not constructive, so it is not obvious what one looks like. In fact, recent results by some friends of mine (still in preprint, so I can't share the reference yet) suggest that one cannot construct such a set directly.

Comment: @RayeesAhmad The pieces mentioned in Banach-Tarski paradox would be a good example.

Comment: Volume = measure is not a geometric interpretation.  It is a redefinition of volume to include sets for which the geometric interpretation of volume no longer applies.

Answer (score 2):

There is no geometric interpretation and there can be no nontrivial interpretation.

Nonmeasurable sets cannot arise through any geometrically meaningful operations, and it is consistent (with set theory minus uncountable Axiom of Choice, which includes all of concrete analysis and much more) to assume that they don't exist.

Therefore, any property that distinguishes measurable from a nonmeasurable sets has to be so ghostly that one can never find an example of a set without that property.   In effect that means that the only distinctions are renamings of the property of being measurable in nearly identical words: whether the set

- has a measure
- has inner measure = outer measure
- has "volume", where volume is defined to mean measure.